# I want to know the exact meaning of "The five of us"

Tags: word-meaning

In this phrase 'The five of us', does 'us' mean just five members? Or can be more than that?

Thank you.

Comment: You could have a room with 100 people.  In the corner, you and four other people are talking together.  If you say "the five of us", it refers to the five person group of which you are a member.

Comment: Thank you. If there are 10 friends in a room, can one of them say to the others that "The five of us will find him."? If possible, what does he mean?

Comment: The phrase refers to the a group that includes the speaker and four others to whom the statement is directed.

Comment: Thank you, Maxw. So you mean ' us ' means 5 people?

Comment: If you say "the **five** of **us**", that refers to a total of five people including yourself.  If you are in a group of ten people and say "the five of us" to the whole group, none of the other nine people will know which four of them you're talking about, and they would wonder where you learned to count.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

"The five of us" means exactly five (5) people one of whom is the speaker.

Answer (score -1):

"The five of us" means five members in a group that have more than five members.

I think soo, I'm a new leaner, I think this is a nearly-correct answer.

Comment: "Us" really refers just to the group (in this case, five people).  There are always other people in the world, and the members of that group can be  members of other groups, too.  Membership in any other groups, or that group as a subset of a larger group, are irrelevant to "us".